# Angular router doesn't see component to redirectTO

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router

I'm trying to create routing for my application. I have main-view module in which I've put :

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { MainViewComponent } from './main-view.component';

export const MAINVIEW_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: 'home',
  component: MainViewComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: [],
    pageTitle: 'home.title'
  }
};
```

I'm also using forChild method in main-view.module

```
imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild([MAINVIEW_ROUTE]), ChartsModule, MagDynoSharedModule, MatGridListModule]
```

In my app-routing.moduling I have this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: '', children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

The app doesnt' display the main-view.component in this router-outlet. Without using redirect another module are loaded.

Comment: Are you trying to do lazy module loading or just doing eager?

Comment: For now eager is enough.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in any of the code you've posted, so I'm guessing what you need to do to eagerly load your main-view.module and its routes is to include that module in your app.module imports.

Comment: It's already included. The funny fact is that if I open localhost/home it works. The problem is with redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already import the MainViewModule in the AppModule,
I think you should configure the AppModuleRouting in this way:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

Then the MainViewRoutingModule should be:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
     { path: 'home', component: MainViewComponent }
])
```

On the other hand, if you want to do Lazy Loading: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

You should do:

AppModuleRouting

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main-view.module').then(mod => mod.MainViewModule)}
];
```

Then in the MainViewModuleRouting should be:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
   { path: '', children: [
        { path: 'home', component: MainViewComponent }
   ]
]);
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but I wanted to have main routing in one file. Anyway this answer is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, because of Jhipster i had some issues.
In my last version I changed the app-routing-module to:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', children: MAINVIEW_ROUTE },
    { path: 'setting', children: SETTING_ROUTE },
    { path: 'history', children: HISTORY_ROUTE },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#MagDynoAdminModule' },
    ...ACCOUNT_ROUTES,
    ...LAYOUT_ROUTES,
  ],
  { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
)
```

And It works well.
But I'm not sure if the better convention is to use it like this( with children):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [{
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', children: MAINVIEW_ROUTE },
        { path: 'setting', children: SETTING_ROUTE },
        { path: 'history', children: HISTORY_ROUTE },
        { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#MagDynoAdminModule' },
        ...ACCOUNT_ROUTES,
        ...LAYOUT_ROUTES
      ]
    }
  ],
  { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
)
```